# Symfony2 save two forms in one action

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I'm new symfony so got stuck in this issue.

I'm saving two different forms in once action. For instance : first i'm saving user detail than get the last inserted id to save another detail like : user hours.

My first form is inserting but second one is not saving the data. Here is my code:

```
    $user = new Users ();
    $user->setName($strUserName);
    $user->setAddress1($strAddress1);
    $user->setAddress2($strAddress2);
    $user->setCity($strCity);
    $user->setState($strState);
    $user->setZip($strZip);
    $user->setContactSales($strContactSales);
    $user->setContactService($strContactService);
    $user->setContactParts($strContactParts);
    $user->setWebsite($strWebsite);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($user);

    $userId = $user->getId();

    $userWorkingHours = new UserWorkingHours();
    $userWorkingHours->setDay = '"' . $day . '"';
    $userWorkingHours->setStartDay = '"' . $startDay . '"';
    $userWorkingHours->setEndDay = '"' . $endDay . '"';
    $userWorkingHours->setLunchHourStart = '"' . $lunchStart . '"';
    $userWorkingHours->setLunchHourEnd = '"' . $lunchEnd . '"';
    $userWorkingHours->setUserId = '"' . $userId . '"';
    $userWorkingHours->setIsActive = '"' . $isActive . '", ';
    $userWorkingHours->setCreatedOn = '"' . time() . '"';
    $userWorkingHours->setType = 1;

    $em->persist($userWorkingHours);
    $em->flush();
```

Please give me the solution guys. I've been stuck here since morning. Thank you

Comment: This is an old school approach.  Take the time to got through the manual and learn to setup relations and such.  After that you won't need to play last insert id games anymore.  Or revert back to the Doctrine database access layer approach.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad for motivating with your true words. I had to deliver this in any case that's why could not spend time on manual. But will surely learn about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

always flush after persist

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

and i dont know what you are doing with these '"'

should be `$userWorkingHours->setDay($day);`

Comment: Thanks @tommygunangel. I've tried that but it's not working.

Comment: Oh god ! Why i did not notice i'was using the wrong syntax. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

Remember you can embed a form inside another form. But first, check if your entities are correctly designed. First one - you are using setters whereas second one is based on public fields.

And don't connect using ids - it's not a preferred way under Doctrine - better to associate these entities and use methods a'la `setUser` for `UserWorkingHours`. You **don't** have to manage everything using keys per se.

Learn the Doctrine basics.

Comment: Thank you @eRiz. I have not read much about it as i am new in this framework. But I will definitely take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $em->persist($user);

  $userId = $user->getId();
```

`persist` method only tells doctrine "mark this object to save it later", so `$user->getId()` has not a value yet. you must use `$em->flush()` first before try to get object id. `flush` method actually saves the entity.

And... what are you trying to do here?

```
$userWorkingHours = new UserWorkingHours();
$userWorkingHours->setDay = '"' . $day . '"';
$userWorkingHours->setStartDay = '"' . $startDay . '"';
...
```

Isn't supposed `setDay` and `setStartDay` to be methods?

I think you have a problem on your entities relations, you should not have a `setUserId`, the correct way must be to have a `setUser` method and call it:

```
$userWorkingHours->setUser($user);
```